# How to interact with a node.js script in the browser?

Tags: node.js, browser

I'm unfamiliar with node and don't know where to start looking, or what exact question to ask.

I have a server on which I can run javascript through node. So:

```
node myfile.js
```

Now, I want to be able to browse to this server, passing a query string variable:

```
https://myserver.com/somefile.html?somevariable=1
```

Then, I want to pass the somevariable to the node script myfile.js, get the result back from myfile.js, and present the result in the browser.

How do I do this?

I'd happily call myfile.js directly in the browser, too, but that won't run the script through node nor would it output the result to the browser.

(More specifically, I want to pass the value of somevariable from a PHP page on another server and then process the result on that PHP page.)

Comment: checkout `expressjs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly, you want to create an API in NodeJS.

Take a look at: https://github.com/expressjs/express

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/someRoute', function (req, res) {

  console.log(req.query.somevariable)

  res.send(`Some Variable: ${req.query.somevariable}`)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

https://localhost:3000/someRoute?somevariable=1

Comment: Your understanding is correct. I'm inheriting an API that I need to get to run.

Comment: The solution above should be what you are looking to do at a basic level. You access the query parameters from req.query.the_variable_name and then pass off to what ever processing function you need and return the result in the res.send().